# How can I / Is it possible to install Freya 3.1 on a MacMini G4?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

I have an old Mac Mini G4 but I am having a hard time installing Freya on it.
I burned the `.iso` to a dvd but when I hold down `C` on startup the system doesn't recognize it as a bootable disc and just loads OSX 10.5.

The machine is too old to run netbootin.

What I am going to try is installing Ubuntu 12.04 then installing netbootin from that OS and creating a usb image to load from.

Having a hard time with this OS as doesn't seem to want to install.

Is it even possible? Maybe PPC chip architecture is not compatible with Freya is what I am beginning to think.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. elementary does not provide images that are compatible with the PPC processor architecture

Answer (score 2):

For PowerPc there are versions of Ubuntu

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads

but elementary OS is not possible.